# how to pass date via ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax

JAVASCRIPT

```
pokazSeanse(x){
[...]
x = "2013-04-25";
xmlhttp.open("GET","main/seanse.php?termin="+x,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

seanse.php

```
$termin = $_GET['termin'];
echo $termin;
```

It shows "`20132013`". I need to get the full date

Comment: You should always encode querystring data, but hyphens should be OK, and `2013-04-25` doesn't suddenly become `20132013`, that's just not posible, so something else is going on here ?

Comment: ahh sry, I just didn't checked two times.. i had intval("$_GET['termin']); 
i changed it to that version above, didn't save my changes, refresh page to see results and thought that still something is wrong.. now it's OK : ) Ty anyway (and sorry for my silliness).